# What does SLE stand for in ITIL?

Tags: methodology, quality-management, customer-service

In ITIL

- An `SLA` is a Service Level Agreement (potentially a legal contract)
- An `SLO` is a Service Level Objective (and thus could be a KPI)
- An `SLR` is a Service Level Requirement (a clause in an SLA? a required level for an SLO?)
- **But what does `SLE` stand for?**

From the context, it looks like it is a *soft* version of an SLA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be `Service Level Expectation`.

From [an article in Information Week](http://www.informationweek.com/service-level-agreements-come-of-age/d/d-id/1074371?) titled *Service-Level Agreements Come Of Age*:

> When you think of SLAs, you might also think of penalties, contract termination, "free" services, and other woes that all too often were part of doing business with Internet service providers. It's little wonder that some organizations, attempting to avoid negative connotations, prefer to use the terms **SLE** (service-level expectation) or SLG (service-level goal).

Comment: Should be right, as the document sais "Every solution has an asset owner [...] who guards that the solution delivers __what the consumer expects__.
The __SLE__ for a solution is initially determined by the SLE from the connected ITServices".